# Getting anchors title and putting into input

Tags: jquery, select, css-selectors

I'm trying to understand, how I could grab anchors title atribute, and insert it into input.

I tried this:

```
$(".choosebox a").click(function () { 
var url = $(this).attr('title');
//alert(url);
$("input").text(url);
return false;
});
```

Alerting works great, but the title is not inserting inside the input.

What might be the correct way to do that?

P.S. If I want point to input one input, not all, then which syntax is appropriate? `$("input[name='this-one']")` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, probably, using `text()` rather than `val()`, an `input` element doesn't really have a `text()` content, rather it has a `value`, which jQuery addresses as `val()`, therefore this should work:

```
$(".choosebox a").click(function () { 
    var url = this.title; // Using the native JavaScript/DOM method for getting the title attribute.
    //alert(url);
    $("input[name='this-one']").val(url);
    return false;
});
```

References:

- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).
- [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).
- [attribute-equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).

Comment: Thanks, mates! But one friend of mine said that I shouldn't mess together jquery and javascript in functions like these. Anyway, it works like charm :)

Comment: Of course, but saying that I thought selecting with DOM methods. For example: getElementById("selectid") and $("#selectid"). Does the same, but one is Javascript DOM, other is jQuery

Comment: That's fair enough, I guess; it's just that sometimes it's faster/easier/more-concise to use native DOM methods. This is one of those times, I think. But your own usage is dependent on the coding/style guidelines of your office. No offence, or negative-criticism, was intended. :)

Comment: No problems, mate ;) Its always good to hear any kind of suggestions or criticism ;)

Answer (score 2):

use instead

```
$("input").val(url);
```